# Can not Turn Off PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, shutdown, fan

After a few days of using dual boot of Windows + Ubuntu, there are problems when I shutdown the PC. Both windows and ubuntu cannot shutdown the PC correctly.

In *Windows* (as comparison), **when I do shutdown**, the PC starting logging off and also say shutting down but it ends with black screen with fan still running. **When I restart the PC**, it's like turning the PC off. The fan is off, the power LED is off, everything turned off but never succeeded doing restart.

In *Ubuntu*, **when I do shutdown**, the process ends with frozen plymouth. **When I restart the PC**, the process is weird. I attemp to reboot the PC and Ubuntu try to stop the service, unmounting the disk, and so on. After all task finished, the PC is turned off for a second and turn back again with normal booting.

I also get these 2 line in text mode in the end of shutdown process:

```
[some numbers] Reboot : System halted.
```

or if not,

```
[some numbers] Reboot : Power down.
```

I have also tried to reinstall both OS, but the problem still persist. I have also tried to suspend and hibernate the PC but never succeed to turn off the PC. Also in different command like init, shutdown, halt, etc.

Any help will be appreciated.